# \titleformat{name=\section} in documentclass

Tags: titlesec, documentclass-writing

I defined a documentclass in which I redefine a heading format with (using the package `titlesec`):

```
\titleformat{name=\section}
```

This works.

But if I move this `\titleformat{name=\section}` to a block `\DeclareOption`, then it does not compile. It say that all the commands in the `\DeclareOption` are already defined.

On the other hand, this format declaration in the `\DeclareOption` block works if I use the syntax `\titleformat{name=\section}`

Is it a bug?

The point is that I want to use two arguments `{name=\section, numberless=true}`; this is why I want to have this syntax.

[EDIT]
Thanks for your post. So here would be an example of the "bug" : documentclass file maclasse.cls :

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{maclasse}[2011/12/19 maclasse]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}

% Sectioning
%% BLOC 1
\titleformat{\section}%
   {\large\sffamily\bfseries}%
   {lasection \arabic{section}}%
   {0.5em}%
   {#1}% 

%% BLOC 2
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless=true}%
   {\sffamily\bfseries}%
  {}%
   {0.5em}%
   {#1}



\DeclareOption{opt}{


}

\ProcessOptions
```

A test file  with

```
\documentclass[opt]{maclasse}

\begin{document}
\section{abc}
abc
\section*{def}
def

\end{document}
```

It compiles.

- Now, move BLOC1 into the \DeclareOption{opt} -> it works.
- Instead, move BLOC2 into \DeclareOption{opt} -> Compilation fails :

  ! LaTeX Error: \RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options Section.

What do i do wrong ?

thanks

nicolas

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You can mark code by selecting it and hitting Ctrl + K (or clicking the `{}` button above the text field). Separate lines will be indented with four spaces, inline code enclosed in backticks (`\``).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be better if you provide an example of what you're trying to do in your class file.

Answer (score 3):

The class should be written differently:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{maclasse}[2011/12/19 maclasse]

% Sectioning
\newif\if@maclasseopt
\DeclareOption{opt}{\@maclasseopttrue}

\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\if@maclasseopt
\titleformat{name=\section}%
  {\large\sffamily\bfseries}%
  {lasection \arabic{section}}%
  {0.5em}%
  {#1}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless=true}%
  {\sffamily\bfseries}%
  {}%
  {0.5em}%
  {#1}%
\fi
```

It's better not to load much code into a `\DeclareOption` command, usually one does with a conditional. Moreover, it's not possible to load `titlesec` before the main class, so the loading must be deferred.

Most important, `\LoadClass` *must* go after `\ProcessOptions`.

Comment: ok, i will try. But i still do not quite understand why the argument {name=\section} makes a problem, and not {section}...

Comment: Ok, finally, i come to test your proposition. Ma class is actually already rather big, and therefore i have to do it carefully, with all the copy paste. Nevertheless, i have a doubt : you write "`\LoadClass` must go after `\ProcessOptions`". But actually, i have a `\LoadClassWithOptions{scrartcl}` at the begining of my class, because in particular, i want the option "draft" to be passed to the class scrartcl. I'm afraid, that loading the class after the `\ProcessOptions` will cause some problem. What do you think ?

Comment: Oh, and please tell me where i should put my `\RequirePackage{}` ?

Comment: @nicolasroy It's quite difficult to tell something with only this information available.

Comment: I'm asking here about the standard structure of a document class. In which order should i write the following blocs : *`\LoadClassWithOptions` , *`\DeclareOption` , *`ProcessOptions`, *`Requirepackage` ?